# Is it possible to not cut off Wordpress excerpts blog posts in the middle of a text line?

Tags: wordpress

URL: http://litepanels.com/blog/

Some of the excerpts from the blog posts have lines cut off in the middle at the end of the excerpt so the letters look cut in half. (example 3rd one down)  Since I am defining a height and the purple headline can be 1,2,3 or 4 lines plus regular copy text this results in different heights.

Is there anything out there that can help with this?

Comment: look into the `more` tag that wordpress offers: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Answer (score 0):

Since this is happening because the title is spanning 3 lines - A possible way is to check how big the title is and then adjust the excerpt from there.

so in your functions.php

this will adjust the excerpt size - make it the amount that you would want it if the title spans over 3 lines

```
function excerptlength($length) {
    return 50; //enter your desired ammount
}
function short_excerpt($length_callback='excerptlength') {
    global $post;
    if(function_exists($length_callback)){
        add_filter('excerpt_length', $length_callback);
    }
    $output = get_the_excerpt();
    $output = apply_filters('wptexturize', $output);
    $output = apply_filters('convert_chars', $output);
    echo $output;
}
```

then add this - which counts the size of the title and if it goes over 70 (or your desired amount) then the excerpt will show the custom size of the excerpt that we set in the previous function

```
function custom_excerpt(){
$title = get_the_title();
$limit = "70"; //enter your desired ammount
$more="...";
if(strlen($title) <= $limit) {
the_excerpt();
} else {
short_excerpt();
}
}
```

and finally on the blog post add this instead of `the_excerpt`

```
<?php custom_excerpt(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> your post Query on <?php the_content(); ?>  to use this code.
> ```
>
> 20(replace you difine your no of words to display)

```
<p><?php $words = explode(" ",strip_tags(get_the_content())); 
$content = implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,20)); echo $content; ?></p>
<?php  if($words): ?>
<p class="more"><a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>">Read More</a></p>
<?php endif;?>


on your css style_main.css line 97:

.post .entry {
    float: left;
    max-height: 128px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 515px;
}

remove :
max-height: 128px;
overflow: hidden;
```